# How to encode/factor new category values from new input/dataset?

Tags: r

I am trying to do regression which has categorical variables as independent variables, the problem is the new dataset has more categories than train dataset. How can I categorize the new values into a specific category like `rare` or `other`?

Assume I have variable like these

```
a <- c("a", "b", "c", "c", "a")
b <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
```

When I do factor on both vectors, it produce the same levels like `"a" "b" "c"`, what should I do so the `b` vector has levels for `d` and `e` that recognized by train dataset which is `a` vector?
I am sorry if I ask a noob question, because I am noob

Answer (score 1):

Create a vector of common elements with `intersect` and assign those new values in `b` (not in common) with `other`

```
common <- intersect(a, b)
b[!b %in% common] <- "other"
```

-output

```
> b
[1] "a"     "b"     "c"     "other" "other"
```

Comment: Oh thank you, this is what I need. But can I add that "other" factor in "a" vector, so "a" vector recognize the "other" factor?

Comment: @abell You can have convert both to `factor` with `levels` as `factor(a, levels = c(common, "other"))` and same with `b`

Comment: you're so helping, thank you so much bro :D